# Access next-i18next translations outside of page/component

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I'm building Next.JS application with Typescript and would like to access next-i18next translations outside of page/component, in order to localize validation messages, while all the validation engine is defined in separate utility class. Have checked next-i18next for any kind of static accessors, but no luck there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I thought the only way is passing the `i18n` as a parameter to your utility class.

```
import { withTranslation, WithTranslation } from 'i18n';
import { checkFunction } from '../utils';

type Props = WithTranslation;

const Page: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const result = checkFunction(props.i18n);
}

export default withTranslation(['common'])(Page);
```

Comment: Thank You, I understand that withTranslation could be used, but I would like to have more solid solution, as in this case it's easy to forget including one of translation namespaces if there are few. I would like to find solution without passing translation function.